# Ruby Class Method Setup

Tags: ruby, class, methods, syntax

I'm going through the Ruby Koans [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) and I'm at a place in "about_class_methods.rb" where there is a discussion of setting up class methods, and the Koans talk about three ways.

The two major ways to write class methods are:

1:

```
class Demo (define/open class)
  def self.method
end
```

2:

```
  class << self
    def class_methods
    end
  end
```

The koans also talk about a third method, I've never seen (that I remember):

```
def Demo.class_method_third_way
end
```

Q1 This third way is actually clearer to me than any other. Is there a reason I don't understand about why no one uses it?

Q2 Why am I wrong in thinking the syntax for 2 should be "self << def name end"? That is "Why is the syntax the way it is?" Does the class Object hold a reference to all Classes and this sticks in the method for the self class?

As always, thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In (early) development classes get renamed as insight grows (not `Person` but `Employee`, not `Job` but one or more `Roles` etc.) This renaming is prone to errors if the class name is hardcoded in the class itself.

Comment: Wow, interesting insight Steenslag!

Comment: This answer is particularly good given the OP is asking about ruby koans. :)  It's a very zen-like answer.

Answer (score 3):

In class body, `self` refers exactly the class object being defined. That's why `def self.some_method` works the same as `def Demo.some_method`.

```
class Demo
  puts self.object_id == Demo.object_id
end
#=> true
```

`class << some_obj` is the syntax to access the singleton class of `some_obj`. Refer to the [Ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Singleton+Classes):

> The singleton class (also known as the metaclass or eigenclass) of an object is a class that holds methods for only that instance. You can access the singleton class of an object using `class << object` ... Most frequently you’ll see the singleton class accessed like this:

```
class C
  class << self
    # ...
  end
  # or
  class << C
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Arie. I read the link. I'm too much of a noob to have it help that much. I also found this: http://www.devalot.com/articles/2008/09/ruby-singleton which covers some of the same ground. In answer to my Q1, I think you're not commenting (which is fine) and in answer to Q2, I think you're expanding on the singleton concept. That said, why isn't Demo.class_method used more often? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @codenoob If you're using `class << self; end`, when you refactor your class name, you don't need to modify the name in this statement block.